# No available mirrors for yaml-cpp

Tags: archlinux, yaml-cpp

I'm trying to install `mongodd` using yaourt on archlinux which require the `yaml-cpp` lib to be installed.

The thing is, yaourt is unable to find a valid mirror to download from

```
error: failed retrieving file 'yaml-cpp-0.6.1-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.swin.edu.au : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'yaml-cpp-0.6.1-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.acc.umu.se : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'yaml-cpp-0.6.1-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.neuf.no : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'yaml-cpp-0.6.1-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.ustc.edu.cn : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'yaml-cpp-0.6.1-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.23media.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
(4/4) checking keys in keyring                            [##############################] 100%
(4/4) checking package integrity                          [##############################] 100%
error: yaml-cpp: signature from "Levente Polyak (anthraxx) <levente@leventepolyak.net>" is invalid
```

I tried building the lib manually from source and putting it in `/usr/lib` but it doesn't work either.

What can I do here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must update your Arch Linux before installing any new package.
The following command are fine:

- `pacman -Syu`  followed by  `pacman -S yaml-cpp`
- `pacman -Syu yaml-cpp`

You must not do this (it may break your system):

- `pacman -Sy`  followed by  `pacman -S yaml-cpp`
- `pacman -Sy yaml-cpp`